# Jquery event handling code doesnt work after including script in head from an external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I included a script into my document's head that contains the following jquery code:

```
    $('.unappreciatedIcon').click(function() {
        alert('JS Works!');
    });
```

In the body of my document I have following:-

```
    <span class="unappreciatedIcon">.....</span>
```

But there is no `alert` displayed when I inserted the script into the document head from an external js file. When I had put this script in body simply below the target elements this worked flawlessly.

---

### Thanks to you all:

I am getting this to work with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.unappreciatedIcon').click(function() {
        alert('fds');
    })
});
```

Comment: Executing this code before your page HTML has been parsed and loaded will do nothing because there are no objects in the page to find and hook up a click handler to.

Comment: There must be something wrong in your page/JS that you aren't showing us because when I following the recommendations here in this jsFiddle, it all works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/y8n2K/.  So, either you have other JS errors or you aren't showing us what is really causing the problem.  Have you looked in the error console or the debugger console to see what errors are reported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you wrap your jquery in a `$(document).ready(function() { // your code // });` ?

If not your jquery code is executing immediately and the browser has not loaded your `span`.  You need to wait for the document to be ready (using the code above) before assigning events.

**Update**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.unappreciatedIcon').click(function() {
        alert('JS Works!');
    });
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready($('.unappreciatedIcon').click(function() {
        alert('JS Works!');
    }));  //          should I do something like this ?? But even this doesnt work..

Comment: You're missing a vital bit: $(document).ready(function(){ [[YOUR CODE GOES HERE]] })

Answer (score 3):

When your script ran, it looked for an element having the class `unappreciatedIcon`. Nothing was found because the document is still being parsed and there was no node having the class `unappreciatedIcon` available in the document *so far*. The DOM is being constructed incrementally.

But when you put your script after the span element occurs, then `$('.unappreciatedIcon')` was found because it has been parsed and added to the DOM, so the click handler was tied to it.

Either run your code in a ready callback. The ready callback basically runs when the entire HTML has been parsed and the DOM is fully constructed which is usually a safe point to start running your JavaScript code that depends on the DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.unappreciatedIcon').click(...)
});
```

or put your code after the element occurs (don't need to wrap it inside the ready callback in this case),

```
<span class="someClass">..</span>
..
<script>
    $('.unappreciatedIcon').click(...)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

just going to go with basics but did you make sure to include the jquery library?  If it doesn't work and it's in the code you can also open in firefox with firebug go to the console tab and see what error you have.

Comment: just a hunch but where you include the Jquery library is the link like this <script src='' /> or is it like this <script src=''></script> if the former then change it to the latter if the latter then that may be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The javascript is being processed before the page has finished rendering. As Erik Philips suggested, you need to put this statement inside your $(document).ready() function to ensure the page is loaded before the statement is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.unappreciatedIcon').click(function() {
 alert('JS Works!');
 });
});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Pf4qp/

Answer (score 0):

Since HTML loads from top to bottom, the head loads before the rest of the page. You could solve this problem by putting the link to your js file right before the  end tag. However, its generally better practice to put the javascript link in the head.

A better alternative is to use the **defer** attribute in the script tag.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer="defer"></script>
```

The second option is kind of unneccessary though. This attribute is pretty well supported. Internet Explorer has supported it since version 5.5 though apparently it is "buggy" through IE9. It has been fully supported since FireFox 3.5, Chrome 8.0, Safari 5.0. It also works with all current mobile browsers. I guess it is not supported by any Opera browsers though.